# Запросы в MySQL

Tags: авторизация, оптимизация, запрос, mysql

У меня есть две таблицы: `users` и `admins`.
В `users` находятся все пользователи, кроме админов. А в `admins` - только админы.
Встал вопрос: как проверить данные пользователя при авторизации на сайте? Если при авторизации у меня запрос типа...

> "SELECT  FROM `users` ..."

А вдруг пользователь `admin`? Тогда нужен второй запрос ...

> "SELECT FROM `admins` ... "

Посоветуйте, как быть? Может есть какие-либо двойные запросы?

Конечно, можно создавать по два запроса с условиями, но может можно оптимизировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Union](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(SQL)) или сделать так и ничего не менять)

Comment: ах, какая полезная функция. Ведь, зная я о ней 4 минуты назад - решил бы проблему за пару секунд. А сейчас я уже изменил таблицы, перенес все данные в одну. И изменил систему. Печально..)
Но спасибо огромное. В следующий раз я  буду знать о такой возможности.

Comment: А кстати, вот всё-таки что лучше использовать в моем случае? Union или использовать только одну таблицу users?

Comment: Лучше использовать одну таблицу, а Union пригодиться вам в другом месте.

Comment: Конечно! Ведь UNION можно использовать в БД только один раз. Так что - экономим.

Answer (score 6):

На мой взгляд ваша архитектура таблиц неверна. Обычно админы и пользователи лежат в одной таблице в которой есть дополнительный параметр (обычно `integer`) который указывает какой группе принадлежит пользователь по нему и определяют админ это или нет. Вообще архитектура существенно зависит от того что вы пишите...
Конкретно в вашем случае проще всего обойтись 2 запросами к БД. При логине сначала проверяете входит ли обычный пользователь, и если авторизация неудачна то запускаем второй запрос который проверит возможно это входит админ.

Comment: Наверное Вы правы, но хотелось бы еще полезных советов почитать.
Но скорее всего сейчас изменю структуру таблицы. Правда потом придется перелопатить код.